# Can I guess the order of magnitude of the current inside a spark based on a picture?

Tags: electricity, estimation, piezoelectric

In this [video](https://youtu.be/wcJXA8IqYl8), Steve Mould explains how an inflammable gas can be ignited with a spark created by the piezoelectric effect. At [01:11](https://youtu.be/wcJXA8IqYl8?si=zbK34wPoZ-4gOFlZ&t=71), there is a close up on the spark with a scale in the background.

[image: Picture of a spark]

I know that if a spark is created, that's because the voltage between the electrodes is so high that the electric field is above a critical limit that makes the air conductive. So it seems easy to guess the order of magnitude of the voltage given the value of the electric field and the distance between the electrodes.

But is there a simple way to "guestimate" the value of the current?

The real goal here is the estimate the energy released by the spark and compare it to the [minimum ignition energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_ignition_energy) of the inflammable gas to see if the orders of magnitude are in the same range.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is - Can the current be estimated from the picture, knowledge of typical piezoelectric igniters, or other information?

Comment: @mmesser314 Only from the picture. My real goal is the estimate the energy released by the spark and compare it to the [minimum ignition energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_ignition_energy) of the inflammable gas to see if the orders of magnitude are in the same range.